# python 3, mover archivos .zip a directorio

Tags: python, python-3.x

intento mover los archivos que tengan la extension ".zip" a la carpeta en mi pc llamada "zip"
pero me da este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ticua\Desktop\Scripts\junk_organizer\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.rename(i, "zip")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'chromedriver_win32.zip' -> 'zip'
```

este es mi codigo:

```
sourcepath='C:/Users/Ticua/Downloads'
files = os.listdir(sourcepath)
for i in files:
    if i.endswith(".zip"):
        os.rename(i, "zip")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema es que el script está ejecutándose en un directorio distinto a donde están los archivos; aunque no es que eso esté mal, si no que hay que indicar las rutas para que el interprete "no se pierda"

El resultado de `os.listdir(sourcepath)` es algo asi `['file1.jpg', 'file2.txt', ...]`. Pero cuando intentas `os.rename('file1.jpg', 'zip')`, python no sabe ni donde está el archivo de origen, y mucho menos el destino.

Y de todas formas, aunque posiciones la ejecución con [os.chdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir), `os.rename()` tiene problemas para procesar archivos de forma relativa.

Suponiendo que hay en Desktop un archivo '`file1.png`', y un directorio, '`Testdir`'

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('C:/Users/***/Desktop')
>>> os.rename('file1.png', 'Testdir')
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
>>>
>>> os.rename('C:/Users/***/Desktop/file1.png', 'Testdir')
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
>>>
>>> os.rename('C:/Users/***/Desktop/file1.png', 'C:/Users/***/Desktop/Testdir/')
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
>>>
>>> os.rename('C:/Users/***/Desktop/file1.png', 'C:/Users/***/Desktop/Testdir/file1.png')
>>> # SUCCESS!!
```

Sin embargo aún hay más problemas. Si hubiese otro archivo `file1.png` en el Desktop y en el directorio `Testdir` ya hay otro archivo con el mismo nombre:

```
>>> os.rename('C:/Users/***/Desktop/file1.png', 'C:/Users/***/Desktop/Testdir/file1.png')
>>> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

Para solucionar esos problemas Python provee otro módulo especialmente pensado para este tipo de menesteres, [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html). Adicional me gusta listar archivos con otro módulo, [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) que posee buenas funcionalidad para búsquedas de patrones, sin embargo tu puedes trabajar con `os.listdir()`, `os.walk()` o lo que desees.

```
import os, shutil, glob

src = 'C:/Users/***/Downloads'
dst = 'C:/users/***/Downloads/Zip'
files = glob.glob1(src, '*.zip')

for i in files:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(src, i), os.path.join(dst, i))
```

Nota: curiosamente el método `glob.glob1()` no está descrito en la documentación oficial pero sería lo mismo que:

```
os.chdir(src)
glob.glob('*.zip')
```